# KivyMD MDSwiper animation problem when using ScrollView

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to do a screen with multiple MDSwiper inside of a ScrollView screen, but the animation of the MDSwiper when swipe event is fired ( the image sizes should be resized ) doesn't works and I can't figure out why. Outside of the ScrollView it works properly.

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class MDNavigationLayout(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class ContentNavigationDrawer(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'TestApp'
        view = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
        return view

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: '8dp'
    spacing: '8dp'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Title'
        font_style: 'Caption'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: 'Item 1'
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state('close')
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: 'account'
<SwiperItem1@MDSwiperItem>:
    RelativeLayout:
        FitImage:
            source: 'image.jpg'
            radius: [20,]
        MDBoxLayout:
            adaptive_height: True
            spacing: '12dp'
            MDLabel:
                text: 'Image1'
                font_style: 'H5'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                pos_hint: {'center_y': .5}
                opposite_colors: True

MDNavigationLayout:
    scrm: scrm
    ScreenManager:
        id: scrm
        main_screen: main_screen
        MainScreen:
            scrm: scrm
            nav_drawer: nav_drawer
            id: main_screen
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, .4
        ContentNavigationDrawer:
            scrm: scrm
            nav_drawer: nav_drawer

<MainScreen>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: 1, 1
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                size_hint_y: .8
                padding: '10dp'
                spacing: '10dp'
                MDSwiper:
                    id: swiper_1
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 260
                    SwiperItem1:
                    SwiperItem1:
                    SwiperItem1:
                MDSwiper:
                    id: swiper_2
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 260
                    SwiperItem1:
                    SwiperItem1:
                    SwiperItem1:
                MDSwiper:
                    id: swiper_3
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 260
                    SwiperItem1:
                    SwiperItem1:
                    SwiperItem1:
```

I need some advice ( maybe is a kivymd bug, idk ), thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should not place scrollable widgets in the ScrollView widget. Kivy has a bug. Can't scroll horizontal content in vertical ScrollView.